# Invalid syntax error for "print expr"?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
import os

import sys, urllib2, urllib

import re

import time

from threading import Thread

class testit(Thread):

    def _init_ (self):

        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):

        url = 'http://games.espnstar.asia/the-greatest-odi/post_brackets.php'

        data = urllib.urlencode([('id',"btn_13_9_13"), ('matchNo',"13")])

        req = urllib2.Request(url)

        fd = urllib2.urlopen(req, data)

        """while 1:

        data = fd.read(1024)

        if not len(data):

        break

        sys.stdout.write(data)"""

        fd.close();

        url2 = 'http://games.espnstar.asia/the-greatest-odi/post_perc.php'

        data2 = urllib.urlencode([('id',"btn_13_9_13"), ('matchNo',"13")])

        req2 = urllib2.Request(url2)

        fd2 = urllib2.urlopen(req2, data2)

        while 1:

            data2 = fd2.read(1024)

        if not len(data2):

            break

        sys.stdout.write(data2)

        fd2.close()

        print time.ctime()

        print " ending thread\n"

i=-1

while i<0:

current = testit()

time.sleep(0.001)

current.start()
```

I'm getting an error stating invalid syntax for the line:

```
print time.ctime()
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You should post the error that was given with your question exactly as shown in your terminal.

Comment: Also, it appears you've lost some indentation at the very least. Make sure the code is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because (in Python 3.0 onwards at least), print is a function.

Use:

```
print (time.ctime())
```

and it should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

From [this page](http://pydoc.org/1.6/time.html#-ctime):

> ctime(...)
>
> ctime(seconds) -> string
>
> Convert a time in seconds since the Epoch to a string in local time.
>
> This is equivalent to asctime(localtime(seconds)).

`ctime` requires an argument and you aren't giving it one. If you're trying to get the current time, try `time.time()` instead. Or, if you're trying to convert the current time in seconds to a string in local time, you should try this:

```
time.ctime(time.time())
```

Comment: ctime no longer requires an argument. Those docs are from a really old version of python (1.6). Even if it did, I think you'd get a TypeError, not a 'invalid syntax' (so presumably a SyntaxError) as being reported here.

time.ctime() will return the current time since Python 2.1.